# Difference in pdf produced from pdflatex and xelatex

Tags: xetex, formatting, pdftex

I am using the same document to compile once with `PdfLaTeX` and once with `XeLaTeX` but the output in both are slightly different as shown here

1. with `PdfLaTeX`: [image: here]
2. with `XeLaTeX` : [image: here]

As you can see, there is a nice contrast in the text while compiling with `PdfLaTeX` which is lost while compiling with `XeLaTeX`. Is there any way that I can achieve the same contrast while using `XeLaTeX`?

Here is the preamble of my document :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} %for boldface math

\usepackage[a4paper, scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

Furthermore, can anyone point out any advantages of using either of the engines in this particular context?

Comment: with the font setup you are showing using xelatex makes no sense.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually, I was comparing the output difference when using `XeLaTeX` with `unicode-math` and without it and so on. I agree that `XeLaTeX` is primarily to use fonts via the `unicode-math` (kindly excuse my primitive knowledge here) but I just wanted to compare the output in any case.

Comment: the problem is not unicode-math or not, but garamondx and [t1]{fontenc}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am borrowing it directly from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue Garamond Expert with NewTX Math](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamondexpertnewtxmath/)

Comment: the whole point of xetex is using OpenType Uniocde fonts and you are forcing T1 a legacy tex-specific encoding and Type1 fonts. you shouldn't use fontenc with xelatex